# Rubyで指定の確率でtrueを返すメソッドはありますか?

Tags: ruby

タイトルの通りです。
とりあえずは以下のようなものを作って対応しています。

```
def hoge(n)
  # true対false が n対100-n になる配列を生成して、ランダムに1つ選択
  ([true] * n + [false] * (100 - n)).sample
end
```

もしなければメソッドのアドバイスを頂けると幸いです。

Answer (score 4):

英語版に同じ質問がありましたので引用します。

```
def choose(weight = 50)
  rand <= weight/100.0
end
```

で如何でしょうか？

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965686/how-to-randomly-choose-true-false-w-weight-in-ruby